# Re-training tesseract 4.0.0-beta.1

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to do number plate recognition using teseract 4.0.0-beta.1. In the github page of tesseract, I found tesseract 4.0 training tutorial for different languages. But, I don't understand how to retrain this network for my use case. I searched for different blogs regarding retraining tesseract, but, was not able to find any. Can someone suggest me some blogs which explain the retraining portion of tesseract 4.0.0-beta.1 for different use cases?